# Does Belarusian milk contain strontium-90 at levels above safety standards?

Tags: radiation, milk, chernobyl

The Associated Press organised to test some milk in Belarus - an area affected by the 1986 [Chernobyl nuclear accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster)

> The state-run Minsk Center of Hygiene and Epidemiology said it found strontium-90, a radioactive isotope linked to cancers and cardiovascular disease, in quantities 10 times higher than Belarusian food safety regulations allow. [...]
>
> The Belarusian Agriculture Ministry says levels of strontium-90 should not exceed 3.7 becquerels per kilogram in food and drink. Becquerels are a globally recognized unit of measurement for radioactivity.
>
> The Minsk lab informed the AP that the milk sample contained 37.5 becquerels.

However, this result was disputed:

> Milkavita chief engineer Maia Fedonchuk rejected the findings.
>
> "It's impossible. We do our own testing. There must have been a mix-up," she said, adding they test samples from every batch of milk they receive from Chubenok and do an "in-depth" analysis every six months. She said the plant's own lab analysis indicates its overall milk supply contains an average of 2.85 becquerels per kilogram.

Is the milk in the Belarusian supply contaminated with nuclear waste above the appropriate safety levels?

Comment: Response - The CPS has denied information appeared in the media, that one of Belarusian farms located on the edge of the exclusion zone, produces and distributes, including in Russia, radioactive milk. Earlier, the AP journalists conducted an investigation, during which, in particular, it was found that the supply of dairy products from Belarusian plant «Savushkin product» may threaten the health of people.

Comment: At the Federal service of the journalists of the Agency RIA «Novosti» emphasized that the Agency continuously monitors food products, including dairy. In the number of monitored indicators and indicators of radiation safety, assured reporters.

Comment: Meanwhile, the Ministry of agriculture and food of Belarus, the journalists also stated that the penetration into Russia of radioactive dairy products from their country are excluded. «Savushkin product» never send radioactive products for export. The Rosselkhoznadzor examines very carefully. The Russians would have long since thrown it from the list of exporters», said the Agency a source in the Ministry.
According to him, in this case we are talking about the aggravation of the situation. «This is nothing more than whipping on the eve of the anniversary of the Chernobyl accident», he added.

Comment: http://en.news-4-u.ru/in-the-cps-ruled-out-the-likelihood-of-radioactive-milk-from-belarus-to-russia.html

Comment: Is it possible that the milk produced there is mixed 1:15 with a clean milk, which puts the 90St levels into normal?

Comment: By comparison: humans and bananas contain about 100 Bq of radioactive materials per kilogram.